# parametrize hypersphere

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I want to find an $n$-vector $\hat{\theta}$ that maximizes a function $f(\theta)$ subject to the $p$-norm constraint $||\theta||_p = c$.

Is there a general parametrization of $p$-norm hyperspheres that makes this easy?

Comment: It depends on the value of $p$: For $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ the unit sphere is a polyhedron, for $1<p<\infty$ a smooth surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard 2-norm hypersphere is parametrized by [hyperspherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Hyperspherical_coordinates), which you can easily turn into a parametrization of the $p$-norm hypersphere by transforming each coordinate as $x_i \mapsto \operatorname{sgn}(x_i) \lvert x_i \rvert^{2/p}$.

However, I would not recommend using this for solving an optimization problem, because the parametrization is singular at the poles, and at many other points when $p \le 1$ or $p = \infty$. You should look into [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) instead.